# break in text using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I want my code to do what it is doing in this snippet but on my browser it's displayed as in the picture. I think it is flexbox causing this issue. Anyone has any idea why this could be and how to fix it?

I have checked whether if it is anything on other classes but this div is completely separate from the other divs and their classes

[image]

```css
.activity-snippets {
  display: flex;
}

.activity-post-link {
  height: 215px;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.activity-post-link img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.activity-post-link a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
  <div class="activity-snippets">

    <div class="activity-post-link">
      <a>
        <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
        <h2>
          My Girl's Cave for $55
        </h2>
        </a>
    </div>


    <div class="activity-post-link">
      <a>
        <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
          <h2>
            Turning a French Door Into a Shower Wall.
          </h2>
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class="activity-post-link">
      <a>
        <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/476251/screenshots/2619255/attachments/523315/placeholder.png">
        <h2>
          LOVE SHELF
        </h2>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: are you sure there is no more CSS ?

Comment: The snippet looks good to me, with text wrapping down as it should. If the snippet looks good in your browser too, then most likely it's something else in your full CSS that's causing the issue. Could you provide a link to the full version?

Comment: Seems like some other css attributes affect your text, maybe a `white-space: nowrap;`. Find it via developer or add this line of code `white-space: normal !important;`

Comment: For us to be able to provide a proper answer, we need a code snippet that actually reproduce the issue you describe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the snippet looks good but your actual full code doesn't, then there must be something else in your code preventing the text to wrap.

Looks like your flex items are being sized correctly but your text is overflowing. Check if there's some `white-space: nowrap;` being applied to those h2s anywhere in your full code.

Comment: Since the issue is not reproduced in the question, any answer will be a guess, and we don't guess here at SO

Comment: @LGSon dude that's not a guess... it's a unequivocal deduction. Her flex-items respect the 33% width but her text overflows, then it's obvious she has a whitespace:nowrap there.

Comment: If you understand Flexbox, you should know there is more to it than that.

Comment: @LGSon and yet the answer got accepted, so it worked.

Comment: Doesn't matter, the question is a poor one, that doesn't provide a proper code snippet reproducing the described issue, and based on that, your answer suites more as a comment. Also, questions like these, together with their answers, is of little use for future users, and will hopefully be deleted.